# Struggling to update button style on press

Tags: javascript, react-native, button

In our code we want the individual button to update style on press and to be able to basically have it update state to where we know it is pressed and can send that it was taken to our database when the submit button is pressed. We have the submit button working but we can't seem to update the seat buttons when we press them to change their color. Instead, we have to wait and reload the page before it changes anything. Here is the code below.

```
export const OrderScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Setting a timer']);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState('Unknown');
  const COL = 5;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); 
  
  const [seats, setSeats] = useState([]);   

  
  const updateSeat = async (taken,rowNum,seat) => {
    const DocRef = doc(db, "Theaters/Seating/Theater1", rowNum);
    await updateDoc(DocRef, {
      [seat] : taken
    });
   
    
  };

var ListofOrders = [];
  function recordOrder(name,qty){
    console.log(name, qty);
    ListofOrders = ListofOrders.filter(function( element ) {
        return element !== undefined;
    });
    if(ListofOrders.length != 0){
        for (let i = 0; i < ListofOrders.length; i++ ){
            //console.log(ListofOrders[i][0]);
            if(ListofOrders[i][0] == name){
                delete ListofOrders[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    var array = [name,qty];
    ListofOrders.push(array);
    //console.log(ListofOrders);

    
};
  const SubmitOrder = async() =>{
    for (let i = 0; i < ListofOrders.length; i++ ){
        const q = query(collection(db, 'Inventory'), where("name" , "==" , ListofOrders[i][0]));
        //console.log(ListofOrders[i][0]);
        const querySnapshot =  getDocs(q);
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id);
            docid = doc.id;
            });
        const dbRef = doc(db, 'Inventory', docid);
            updateDoc(dbRef, {
            qty: ListofOrders[i][1]
        });
            }
            console.log("successful");
    };
   function seatTaken(position){
    switch(position){
      case true: return(styles.seatButton); break;
      case false: return(styles.seatButtonTaken); break;
    }
  };

  //function handleClick (){
  //  setState('buttontaken')
 // }


  useEffect(() => {
    const getInventory = async () => {
      const inventorySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Inventory"));
      const inventoryList = inventorySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      setData(inventoryList);
     // console.log(inventoryList);
  };
  getInventory();
  const getSeating = async () => {
   
    const seatSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Theaters/Seating/Theater1"));
    const seatList = seatSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    setSeats(seatList);
   //console.log(seatList);
  };
  getSeating();


}, [])

  return (   
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView>
      <Text style={styles.screenTitle}>New Order</Text>
    {/* Theater Selection */} 
      <Text style ={styles.text}> Ticket Order</Text>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={order}
        onValueChange={(value, index) => setOrder(value)}
        mode="dropdown" // Android only
        style={styles.picker}
      >
        <Picker.Item label="Please select your Order" value="Unknown" />
        <Picker.Item label="Theater 1 5PM" value="Theater 1" />
        <Picker.Item label="Theater 2 5PM" value="Theater 2" />
      </Picker>
    
    
    {/* Seat Animation */}  
    {seats.map((seats,index1,index2,index3) =>(
      <React.Fragment>
        <View style = {styles.containerseats}>
          <Text style = {styles.itemText}> Row {index1 + 1} </Text>
          <Button  key = {seats} style = {seatTaken(seats.A)}  onPress = {() =>  updateSeat(false, 'Row' + (index1 + 1),'A')}/>
          <Button  key = {index1} style = {seatTaken(seats.B)} onPress = {() =>  updateSeat(false, 'Row' + (index1 + 1),'B')}/>
          <Button  key = {index2} style = {seatTaken(seats.C)} onPress = {() =>  updateSeat(false, 'Row' + (index1 + 1),'C')}/>
          <Button  key = {index3} style = {seatTaken(seats.D)} onPress = {() =>  updateSeat(false, 'Row' + (index1 + 1),'D')} />
        </View>
      </React.Fragment> 
    ))}
    {/* Food order */}
    {data.map((data,qty) =>(
        <React.Fragment>
          <View style = {styles.parent}>
            <View style = {styles.block}>
              <Text key = {data} style = {styles.itemText}> {data.name}</Text>            

            </View>
            <View style = {styles.block} >
              
              <Counter  start = {parseInt(0)} max = {parseInt(data.qty)}  onChange={(len, type) => {
                console.log(len, type);
                qty = len;
                recordOrder(data.name,qty);
              }} />
            </View>

          </View>
        </React.Fragment>
        
           
      ))}


    
    {/* Buttons */}
     <Button style={styles.buttonsubmit}  onPress = {() => SubmitOrder()}>
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit Order</Text>
      </Button>
      
      <Button style={styles.borderlessButtonContainer} borderless
        title={'Cancel Order'}
      onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('CustomerHomeScreen')} />
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
        
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  screenTitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: Colors.orange,
    paddingTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: Colors.orange,
    paddingTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    width: '10%',
    height: 18,
    marginTop: 8,   
     alignItems: 'center',

    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginRight:8
  },
   buttonsubmit: {
   width: '50%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 8,
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  buttontaken: {
    width: '10%',
    height: 18,
    marginTop: 8,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    borderColor: Colors.white,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderRadius:8,
    marginRight:8,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',

  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.white,
    fontWeight: '700',

  },
  borderlessButtonContainer: {
    marginTop: 16, 
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  picker: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    width: 300,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 5,
    color: Colors.black,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
 containerseats: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    alignContent: 'space-around',
    padding: 5
},
seatButton: {
    width: '10%',
    height: 18,
    marginTop: 8,
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginRight:8
},
seatButtonTaken: {
    width: '10%',
    height: 18,
    marginTop: 8,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    borderColor: Colors.white,
    padding: 9,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderRadius:8,
    marginRight:8,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
},
itemText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#ff9361',
},
parent: {
    
  flexDirection: "row",
  
},
block: {
  flex: 3,
  margin: 6,
},
  });
```

It is pulling from a firebase database and looks like the image below. I would like the button I press to immediately update the style of that button to seatbuttontaken style instead of seatbutton. Please let me know if there's any other helpful information I can provide.

[image]

Comment: What's the data structure of seats ?  I might have missed something but what should we expect seats.A, seats.B and so on to return from your map?

Comment: The seats are rows of seats and each seat in that row is labeled A,B,C, or D within that row basically on firebase each row is a document and each seat in that row is a different boolean field value of name A,B,C, or D. So seats.A would return all of column one.